# How i get value return from other class (java)

Tags: java, return, return-value, return-type

how i get return value from other class.

1st class apa.java

```
public String cariSPP(String angkatan) throws SQLException{
    String jumlah = null;
    apa iii = new apa();
    iii.terimaCari(jumlah);
    return jumlah;
}

public String terimaCari(String cari){
    return cari; //how i get this return?
}
```

my 2nd class

`apa.cariSPP(angkatan); //send value 
 a = terimaCari(angkatan);`

thank you

Comment: This is a very basic question best handled by taking a Java tutorial. If you do have a specific question about parameter passing and return values, you should make sure you provide an MCVE (https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Not exactly sure what you're asking. You make the call but don't store the returned value.

```
public String cariSPP(String angkatan) throws SQLException{
    String jumlah = null;
    apa iii = new apa();
    String storedValue = iii.terimaCari(jumlah);
    // now do what you want with storedValue
    return jumlah;
}

public String terimaCari(String cari){
    return cari; //how i get this return?
}
```

In the second class, you store the value.

```
apa.cariSPP(angkatan); //send value 
a = apa.terimaCari(angkatan);  // use class to call
```